# Is there a way to modify the wifi_config_t ssid/password data on the fly?

Tags: c, function, task, esp32, esp-idf

ESP-IDF 5.0, win 10. ESP32 Devkit v1 REV3

Consider the following simple (pseudo)code:

```
#include <everything necessary>

static void wifi_event_handler(args) //Declaring the wifi handler function
{ *some code*}

static void wifi_enable(args)  //Declaring wifi and netif init function
{ 
        *wifi init code*;

        wifi_config_t wifi_config = { //Decalring the wifi config struct
            <wifi ssid/pass here>
        };

        *wifi start and connect code*;

}

void app_main(void)
{

    wifi_enable();

    while(1) {vTaskDelay(1000/portTICK_PERIOD_MS);}

}
```

The code compiles and works just fine. However, is there any way to change the values of the wifi_config struct from the app_main or some other functions? I.e. if I wanted to change ssid/pass on the fly from a fucntion running inside app_main.

I am aware that whatever is declared in function is only addressable from within that function. But since starting WIFI on ESP32 creates a separate Wifi task bound to a separate CPU core, I was wondering if changing values of wifi_config struct would still be possible. Thank you.

Comment: Just terminate the wifi handler and restart it with a new SSID/password (something like `WiFi.end(); WiFi.begin(newSsid, newpassword);`

Comment: @PMF Thanks, but I use the ESP-IDF's api, so no Arduino components. Hence can't use the WiFi.end().

Comment: Then why are you omitting the wifi start and connect code in your question? That's anyway the part that would be relevant to answer this question.